# Read only geometry from shapefile with python/geopandas

Tags: python, shapefile, fields-attributes, fiona, geopandas

I would like to open a shapefile(shp) without loading the attributes(dbf), as I do not care about attributes and it takes about 25 minutes to load them. I am using Python Geopandas, so any Fiona or Osgeo solution is useful.

I want the results from below code, but not the waiting time!

> geometry =
>   GeoDataFrame.from_file('easyshapes_bigattributes.shp').geometry

Comment: You could just temporarily rename the .dbf file, so it will not be recognised as part of the shapefile, and therefore will not be loaded

Comment: awesome. works like a charm

Comment: Easy as long as you don't have loads of shapefiles!

Comment: I will rename the file with python :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in my comment, simply rename the .dbf file, so it will not be recognised as part of the shapefile, and therefore will not be loaded.